# How to create a button for sensor

Tags: java, android, onclick, sensors

I have created a code for my sensor to work, but i wanna to enable and be able to disable it by pressing a button like that:

```
shake_on.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {            
            @Override 
            public void onClick(View v) { 
                if (isSensorActivated) {
                    shake_on.setImageResource(R.drawable.shake_on);
                      sensorManager.registerListener(this, sensorManager.getDefaultSensor(Sensor.TYPE_ACCELEROMETER), SensorManager.SENSOR_DELAY_NORMAL);

                }
                    else {
                        sensorManager.unregisterListener(this);
                           shake_on.setImageResource(R.drawable.shake_off);
                   }
            }

        });
```

Although right now it doesn't let me register and unregister like that inside a onclick method,can someone help me please.

Comment: It is the same thing, and that is me again -_-

Answer (score 2):

When you are creating an *OnClickedListener* , ***this*** actually references to the Listener, so it doesn't work because your newly created *OnClickedListener* is not a *SensorListener*.To refer to the Fragment/Activity that you want to register you should use:

```
Activity.this
```

or

```
Fragment.this
```

and replacing Activity/Fragment with the actual name.